# Prove only using set theory laws and probability definition that $P(A \setminus C)+P(B \setminus A)+P(C\setminus B) \leq P(A \cup B \cup C)$.

Tags: probability-theory

I am having trouble proving that $P(A \setminus C)+P(B \setminus A)+P(C\setminus B) \leq P(A \cup B \cup C)$. Can I get some help?

Comment: Draw a diagram. You are only excluding $A \cap B \cap C$. Also, the definition of probability varies; it's probably best to include what you have learnt it to be.

Comment: I have drawn the diagram and understand that it is true, although the Venn diagram is not considered a proof.

Comment: Presumably the definition of probability you're using either defines or implies that $A\subseteq B\implies P(A) \leq P(B)$? If so, just show the inclusion holds.

Comment: I have learnt it so that $P(\Omega)=1, P( \emptyset )=0, P(A) \geq0$ and that $\sigma$-additivity applies.

Comment: $\sigma$-additivity (indeed even finite additivity) implies that $P(A)\le P(B)$ whenever $A\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 1):

The same idea as in Stefanos's answer, but simpler: we have
$$
(A\setminus C)\cup(B\setminus A)\cup(C\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B\cap C) = A\cup B\cup C,
$$
and the four sets on the left-hand side are pairwise disjoint. (Verifying these statements is a quick set theory exercise.) Therefore by additivity of probabilities,
$$
P(A\setminus C)+P(B\setminus A)+P(C\setminus B)+P(A\cap B\cap C) = P(A\cup B\cup C),
$$
and you only need to note that $P(A\cap B\cap C)\ge0$ to finish the proof.

Comment: I understand this solution well, however I would need to prove the first equation we have, probably using set theory, how would I start? I can't seem to just presume that this is true. Thank you!

Comment: No, of course you should show the set identity is true. It's common to prove that two sets are equal by proving both inclusions: left-hand side $\subseteq$ right-hand side, and right-hand side $\subseteq$ left-hand side. Probably the latter is less straightforward: what can you say about a point $x$ that is in $A\cup B\cup C$ but is not in $A\cap B\cap C$?